# Showing 404 error after hosting a webapp in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have created a Blog web App using react Js ,  it is working fine on my local system but after hosting it  ,it is showing 404 status code . I have used  fake json-server  package to launch  on my local system  but after hosting it with the github it is fetching  no data from json file.
This is the webapp https://manishya1669.github.io/BlogWebApp/ and  this is the code for Blogdetails and for more clearity you can see the whole code source on https://github.com/manishya1669/BlogWebApp

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

const BlogDetails = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    const {data:blog, error,isPending} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs/' + id);
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleClick = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs/' + blog.id, {
          method: 'DELETE'
        }).then(() => {
          history.push('/');
        }) 
      }
    return ( 
          <div className= "blog-details">
             
             {isPending && <div> Loading</div> }
             {error && <div>{error}</div>}
             { blog &&(
                 <article>
                     <h2>
                         {blog.title}
                     </h2>
                     <p> Written by {blog.author}</p>
                     <div>{blog.body}</div>
                     <button onClick={handleClick}>Delete</button>
                 </article>
            )
                   
             }
          </div>   );
}
export default BlogDetails;

  

**Hope this is enough to make my self clear and  appreciating those who are willing to help**
```

Comment: Post the errors on your console to this thread.

Comment: Your build failed, citing lack of a `/docs` folder in your gh-pages branch.

Comment: what is the react version you are using in this react app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its solution , it was not following `Cors policy`  because
I was running my whole Client side on port no 3000 and trying to receive data from port 8000, So  due to two different port it was considering two different website where one is trying to retrieve data from other also  that website was not secure . So to deal with this you have add a `proxy` server in your `package.json` for example

```
"name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

Also  you have to  replace   `fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs/' + blog.id,`

with  `fetch('/blogs/' + blog.id,`

```
const handleClick = () => {
        fetch(/'blogs'/+ blog.id, {
          method: 'DELETE'
        }).then(() => {
          history.push('/');
        }) 
      }
```

If you find and any mistake  please  let me know  it would help  me  to learn  more.